# What is the difference between 'There is a pencil there.' and 'There is a pencil.'?

Tags: adverbs, existentials, redundancy, locative

I want to know the difference between the two sentences above.

1. There is a pencil there.
2. There is a pencil.

I think that 'there' is unnecessary in No.1 sentence.

Would you please tell me the difference?

Comment: There is a pencil (where)? "There is" refers to existence, not location (without specific context). 1. by itself is ambiguous.

Comment: ...and thus, the second _there_ in the first sentence is _not_ unnecessary.

Comment: Consider the sentence "there is a pencil here". Usually "here" is the opposite of "there", but here there is no contradiction or confusion: the word "there" does not have its usual meaning.

Comment: @laugh Heh! _"...here there is no contradiction..."_ is all that was necessary. It's positively Hofstadterian.

Comment: Glad you noticed it :)

Answer (score 7):

In English, we use the expression *"there +BE"* to talk about the existence of something. When used in this way, *there* is not a locative. Some examples:

> There are unicorns in the garden.
>   There's not a cloud in the sky.
>   There's no time to waste.
>   There were three in the bed.
>   *"There is a tide in the affairs of men..."*

In your first example, the second *there* is a *locative adverb* that tells us about the location of the pencil:

> There is a pencil *there*.

In conversation, this statement might be accompanied by a gesture indicating the pencil's location. The sentence means *"A pencil exists, and it is located there".*

Without the second and locative *there,* the sentence means only *"A pencil exists".*